# file_get_contents returns 403 forbidden

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to make a sitescraper. I made it on my local machine and it works very fine there. When I execute the same on my server, it shows a 403 forbidden error.
I am using the [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm). The error I get on the server is this:

> Warning:
>   file_get_contents(http://example.com/viewProperty.html?id=7715888)
>   [function.file-get-contents]: failed
>   to open stream: HTTP request failed!
>   HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden in
>   /home/scraping/simple_html_dom.php on
>   line 40

The line of code triggering it is:

```
$url="http://www.example.com/viewProperty.html?id=".$id;

$html=file_get_html($url);
```

I have checked the php.ini on the server and allow_url_fopen is On. Possible solution can be using curl, but I need to know where I am going wrong.

Comment: Is the server yours? If so, it appears that you or your hosting service have configured security settings to prevent being scrapped.

Comment: Its not 'my' server, but its a dedicated server.

Comment: I misread the question. I thought you were scrapping your own site (i.e., a site you have explicit permission to scrape). @Pekka has it right.

Comment: Voting to close as too broad. If the server returns 403 it means the request is forbidden. If it's not your server, there's no way to know anything beyond that.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is not a problem with your script, but with the resource you are requesting. The web server is returning the "forbidden" status code.

It could be that it blocks PHP scripts to prevent scraping, or your IP if you have made too many requests.

You should probably talk to the administrator of the remote server.

Comment: But at the same time, it works just fine on my localhost. The problem seems to be with my server config somehow.

Comment: @absk no, the `403 forbidden` is clearly from the remote server. The connection works fine - try a different IP to verify. It could be that your server's IP is blocked on the remote server's end

Answer (score 87):

PHP provides some means to debug such errors, namely

- a special `$http_response_header` variable, which gets populated after each `file_get_contents()` call with response HTTP headers,
- and `ignore_errors` [context option](https://www.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php#context.http.ignore-errors). By setting it, you'll be able to get the actual response that would likely contain the explanation, why you are getting a 403 response.

Refer for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52662522/285587) for the details.

From the practical point of view, most likely your request lacks some required HTTP header. For example, it could be `Referer` or `User-Agent`.

A list of common user agents used by browsers are listed below:

- Chrome: `'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'`
- Firefox: `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:75.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/75.0`
- etc...

---

```
$context = stream_context_create(
    array(
        "http" => array(
            "header" => "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36"
        )
    )
);

echo file_get_contents("www.google.com", false, $context);
```

This piece of code, fakes the user agent and sends the request to https://google.com.

References:

- [`stream_context_create`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php)

Cheers!

Comment: Either `"header" => "User-Agent: <signature>"` or `"user_agent" => "<signature>"` [would do](http://php.net/manual/en/context.http.php).

Answer (score 11):

Add this after you include the simple_html_dom.php

```
ini_set('user_agent', 'My-Application/2.5');
```

Answer (score 7):

It seems that the remote server has some type of blocking. It may be by **user-agent**, if it's the case you can try using curl to simulate a web browser's user-agent like this:

```
$url="http://www.example.com/viewProperty.html?id=".$id;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can change it like this in parser class from line 35 and on.

```
function curl_get_contents($url)
{
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
  $data = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  return $data;
}

function file_get_html()
{
  $dom = new simple_html_dom;
  $args = func_get_args();
  $dom->load(call_user_func_array('curl_get_contents', $args), true);
  return $dom;
}
```

Have you tried other site?

Comment: But how is this supposed to fix a remote 403?

Comment: He mentioned cURL, so the first part of answer was for that and second "Have you tried other site?", or he might give us a link to check. I know 403 is remote that is why I am suggesting him to try on other site.

Comment: So its fetching data from other sites. Seems my IP just got blacklisted. Any way through?

Comment: You can buy another IP, or scrape data from shared hosting to make it less obvious, but they can block other IP's as well. First try from other server and make pauses when you scrape to look more like a normal user.

Answer (score 3):

Write this in simple_html_dom.php for me it worked

```
function curl_get_contents($url)
{
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
$html = curl_exec($ch);
  $data = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  return $data;
}

function file_get_html($url, $use_include_path = false, $context=null, $offset = -1, $maxLen=-1, $lowercase = true, $forceTagsClosed=true, $target_charset = DEFAULT_TARGET_CHARSET, $stripRN=true, $defaultBRText=DEFAULT_BR_TEXT, $defaultSpanText=DEFAULT_SPAN_TEXT)
{
    $dom = new simple_html_dom;
  $args = func_get_args();
  $dom->load(call_user_func_array('curl_get_contents', $args), true);
  return $dom;
    //$dom = new simple_html_dom(null, $lowercase, $forceTagsClosed, $target_charset, $stripRN, $defaultBRText, $defaultSpanText);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is an old question, but...

Just setting up my local sandbox on linux with php7 and ran across this. Using the terminal run scripts, php calls php.ini for the CLI. I found that the "user_agent" option was commented out. I uncommented it and added a Mozilla user agent, now it works.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check your permissions on file? I set up 777 on my file (in localhost, obviously) and I fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You also may need some additional information in the conext, to make the website belive that the request comes from a human. What a did was enter the website from the browser an copying any extra infomation that was sent in the http request.

```
$context = stream_context_create(
        array(
            "http" => array(
                'method'=>"GET",
                "header" => "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) 
                            AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
                            Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36\r\n" .
                            "accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,
                            image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3\r\n" .
                            "accept-language: es-ES,es;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,it;q=0.7\r\n" . 
                            "accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br\r\n"
            )
        )
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the server was rejecting HTTP 1.0 protocol via it's .htaccess configuration. It seems `file_get_contents` is using HTTP 1.0 version.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:
if you use -> file_get_contents

```
$context  = stream_context_create(
  array(
    "http" => array(
      "header" => "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36"
    )
));
```

=========
if You use curl,

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36');
```

Answer (score 0):

Test your API endpoint with Postman. It will provide more details of the error. In my case, It said the referer is empty. You can add the referer in the header.

curl example

```
curl_setopt(
  $handle,
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
    [
      'Content-Type: application/json',
      'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string),
      'Referer: https://test.com'
    ]
);
```

file_get_content example

```
$header = array(
  "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
  "Referer: https://test.com",
);
$opts = array('http' =>
  array(
    'method' => 'POST',
    'header' => implode("\r\n", $header),
    'content' => $postdata
  )
);
```

This happened on the Google API with restriction mode. So another solution is removing the restrictions

[image]