# PHP geoplugin php error

Tags: php, plugins, geo

i added the plugin from geoplugin.com to my page, i activated my domain, but in my errorlog i get errors all the time like this:

```
[20-Mar-2013 11:17:13 CET] PHP Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip=157.55.34.183&amp;base_currency=USD) [<a href='function.file-get-contents'>function.file-get-contents</a>]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
 in /wwwroot.wwwnew/templates/geo/geoplugin.class.php on line 105
```

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: If you are banned there is no way to solve that problem (only to change/hide your IP perhaps). 
I am opening that url without problems..

Comment: I dont think that im banned.

Comment: Try this same code on a different machine and it will work ! 
Probably your IP is blocked as Svetilo said! You can even try a different site from that same machine. It will probably work too, your code is ok and your server connects to remote ones successfully so it's an issue with the remote server forbidding the request

Comment: please refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545790/file-get-contents-returns-403-forbidden) this may help you.

Comment: please refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545790/file-get-contents-returns-403-forbidden). this may help you.

Answer (score 1):

> If geoplugin.net was responding perfectly, then stopped, then you have
>   gone over the free lookup limit of 120 requests per minute.
>
> We automatically block all requests coming from an IP or a domain name
>   if the number of requests exceeds 120 lookups per minute. This is
>   explained in our Acceptable Use Policy. This block comes in the form
>   of a HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden reply from geoplugin.net
>
> This block is automatically removed 1 hour after the last time your
>   server stopped sending more than 120 requests a minute.

- [GeoPlugin FaQ](http://www.geoplugin.com/faq)

If you need more than 120 requests per minute, you have to [whitelist your domain](http://www.geoplugin.com/premium) (it's paid).