# PHP file_get_contents() on a website which has gone offline - what gets returned?

Tags: php, web, file-get-contents, offline

This isn't in the php documentation on php.net - so I asked here.

If I were (for example) to use `$contents = file_get_contents("www.bbc.co.uk/news")` while `www.bbc.co.uk/news` was **offline**, what would `file_get_contents()` return to my php script in the variable `$contents`?

Would `$contents` be empty? Or would `$contents` be some form of error? (for example) such as

[image]

when viewing in chrome? (hypothetically)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should return FALSE.

See here: [file_get_contents](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

'On failure, file_get_contents() will return FALSE.'

You can always test it by entering a fake URL, i.e a URL that cannot be reached.

You can check the response code (to see if it's a 404) by using:

```
file_get_contents("http://example.com");
var_dump($http_response_header);
```

This is taken from the answer to this question: [HTTP requests with file_get_contents, getting the response code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15620124/http-requests-with-file-get-contents-getting-the-response-code)

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php

Comment: But note, that calling a *invalid* url on a *valid* server adress will most likely redirect you to the servers 404 page, which will then be downloaded as a string.

Comment: Is there a way to detect if the server's 404 page are the contents downloaded or not? @dognose

Comment: The best way would be to check the response code, see updated answer.