# PHP SOAPClient equivalent of CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION?

Tags: php, soap, php-curl

I am able to create raw XML and communicate with the server using curl with CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION set to true. According to the service provider 307 redirects are the rule, and the hosts can change at any time.

The XML for this project is massive and verbose.  I do not want to work with raw XML; I want to use SOAPClient.

This SOAPClient code results in **SoapFault "message":protected]=> string(25) "Could not connect to host"**

```
$url = "https://vmi21.example.net/VMIService.asmx";
$options = [ 'trace' => 1 ];

$soapClient = new SOAPClient($url . '?wsdl', $options );

try
{
    $result = $soapClient->GetCompanyList( $params );
}
catch (SoapFault $soapFault)
{
    var_dump($soapFault);
}
```

After much debugging I noticed a URL in the trace:

```
...
[1]=> string(41) "https://vmi8.example.net/VMIService.asmx"
...
```

Assuming that this is where the 307 redirected the curl I set the following in the SOAPClient options, and it worked!

```
[ 'location' => 'https://vmi8.example.net/VMIService.asmx' ]
```

As mentioned above, according to the service provider these hosts can change at any time, which means that this code would probably break frequently.

**Is there any way to tell SOAPClient to follow these redirects like curl does with the CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION option set to true?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should follow redirects by default, it's unlikely you'd be seeing that message due to a redirection failure.

However, if you do need to specifically change redirect behaviour, just create a context for the connection:

```
<?php
$ctx = stream_context_create(["http" => ["follow_location" => 1]]);
$options = ["trace" => 1, "stream_context" => $ctx];
$soapClient = new SOAPClient("$url?wsdl", $options);
```

It's likely there's a firewall issue or some kind of problem with their response though, which is causing this. If, as you suggest, it works with cURL, perhaps a good strategy might be using cURL or [file_get_contents](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15620189/1255289), disabling redirects, getting the contents of the Location header and feeding it to the SoapClient constructor?

Comment: Adding the stream_context code did not work, as you suggested it wouldn't, however using file_get_contents was genius.  I was able to dig the location header out of $http_response_header, and feed that to the location option when spooling up the SOAPClient.  Thanks a lot!