# Any way to force PHP SOAP to call HTTPS instead of HTTP?

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have a VERY simple PHP code:

```
<?php

$soap = new SoapClient('https://rev-int.api.us.fleetmatics.com/Vehicle/SageQuest/VehicleService.svc?wsdl', array());

var_dump($soap);
```

When I copy that URL into my browser it loads just fine, with no redirects or anything:
$soap = new SoapClient('https://rev-int.api.us.fleetmatics.com/Vehicle/SageQuest/VehicleService.svc?wsdl

But when I execute that PHP script I get the following error after a PHP timeout:

```
Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://rev-int.api.us.fleetmatics.com/Vehicle/SageQuest/VehicleService.svc?wsdl=wsdl0' : failed to load external entity "http://rev-int.api.us.fleetmatics.com/Vehicle/SageQuest/VehicleService.svc?wsdl=wsdl0"
```

Notice the response URL is `http://rev-int.api.us.fleetmatics.com/Vehicle/SageQuest/VehicleService.svc?wsdl=wsdl0` which is very similar but not quite accurate.  If I search the working WSDL for that given URL I find it at the top:

[image]

That said, every URI points to HTTP instead of HTTPS, but if we simply change this in our browser the page loads just fine.

So the question becomes: **when we create a PHP SoapClient, can we force all URIs to follow HTTPS regardless of the protocol specified in the WSDL?**

Comment: Is there a server-side redirect in place? Maybe check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/52304549/231316 for debugging

Comment: Negative on the redirect.  It's strictly that the WSDL (which is being loaded over HTTPS) is linking to NON-HTTPS (that is: HTTP) resources, which don't exist.

Answer (score 1):

The WSDL can stand by itself and contain everything inside, or it can use imports to bring in content from other locations (it usually happens with XSD schemas).

If it imports things, those imports need to be resolved by the client. If they can't be resolved, either because the location is wrong, or the protocol is wrong, or whatever, then the client bails out, because it needs a complete WSDL to understand the service's contract and how to call it, not just the parts it could load.

So you have two options:

1. Contact the provider of the service and ask them to fix it so all imports can be resolved.
2. If you can download the WSDL and all the resources it tries to import, by opening in browser and changing the protocol to https, you can save them all locally on disk in the same folder. Assuming you end up with a file named `VehicleService.wsdl` for the WSDL itself, and `VehicleService.xml` for the file you got from `http://rev-int.api.us.fleetmatics.com/Vehicle/SageQuest/VehicleService.svc?wsdl=wsdl0` somehow, you can then change the WSDL to import this local file with `<wsdl:import .... location="VehicleService.xml" />` instead of what it does right now. Then you can feed this local WSDL to your client, and because now everything is in the same folder, it should work.