# How to catch errors when using file_get_contents on an external URL

Tags: php, file-get-contents

To make a POST request to an external url from my PHP code, I use the following snippet, posted in many topics on here:

```
function http_post($url, $data) {
    $options = ['http' => ['header' => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",'method' => 'POST','content' => http_build_query($data)]];
    $result = file_get_contents($url, false, stream_context_create($options));
    if ($result === FALSE) { /* Handle error */}
    return $result;
}
```

This works, but I'm struggling with the "Handle error" part. How should I implement this? More specifically:

- How would I get a text version of what went wrong to store in my logs? Some of them I can of course catch by surrounding the file_get_contents in a try-catch block, but what about the cases that silently return `false`?
- How can I know if it's an error of type 'timeout'/'connection issue' (in which case I want to try again) or of type 'website not found'/'access denied'/etc. (in which case I don't want to try again)?

Comment: Could look at response headers and determine from there. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15620124/http-requests-with-file-get-contents-getting-the-response-code

Comment: I suggest you using PHP Curl. It's simple and powerful. If you need an example, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

file_get_contents() exists to simplify it's usage so the developer doesn't have to deal with all technical details such as if the retrieved file is on a local storage or retrieved over the netwerk. In some cases file_get_contents() is simple enough.

Perhaps this function can give you some more insight into what went wrong:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-get-last.php

```
if (!$result = @file_get_contents($url, false, $context)) {
    $error = error_get_last();
    echo "Error: " . $error['message'];
}
```

If you want more power over your requests and it's responses, you might need to look into other libraries such as curl (https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)