# PHP Failed to open stream HTTP request failed

Tags: php, warnings

Is this error due to my IP block or what?

If yes then blocking which IP? on which I have put my script to execute

I am getting this error:

> Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.yelp.com/biz/allegro-romano-san-francisco):
>   failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden in
>   /var/www/html/scrap/yelp/simple_html_dom.php on line 75

Is there any way to get rid of this?

Comment: you can have a look at this thread   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545790/file-get-contents-returns-403-forbidden

Comment: Works for me with a bogus UA, so it's probably not UA blocking. What is your request data like? Are you making millions of requests to their site? What you need to do is test it on a different machine, or use tor.

Comment: working also for me try $c = file_get_contents('http://www.yelp.com/biz/allegro-romano-san-francisco');
print_r($http_response_header);

Comment: wow, had no idea about the `$http_response_header` variable.

Comment: @RPM: yes, made around 3k rwquests

Comment: Well, you should chill out on those requests from that single machine, and at least change your IP addressees often. and make sure you send a user agent similar to a browser. Fire up some VM's dynamically after N requests.

Comment: @RPM: can you please elaborate "make sure you send a user agent similar to a browser. "

Comment: I used web proxies, they even gives same error

Comment: Take a look at the user agent sent via your own browser in the "network" tab when you request stackoverflow.com

Comment: did you mean tools/advance/network tab? there it shows system proxy

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem with your script, but with the resource you are requesting. The web server is returning the "**forbidden**" status code.