# Evolution Script 5.1 BitCoin Payment Gateway Error

Tags: php

I'm checking on Evolution Script `5.1 PTC Script` and when I activated the `BitCoin Payment Gateway` and try to add some funds in it, I get this error:

```
Warning: file_get_contents failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden in /home/u991806379/public_html/Sources/blockchain.php on line 40
```

Can anyone help me sort it out?

Comment: possible duplicate of [file\_get\_contents returns 403 forbidden](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545790/file-get-contents-returns-403-forbidden)

Comment: I am no programmer so I really don't know how to work it out.

What do I need to do?

Comment: This is the lines of code I am getting the error:

if ($order['bc_address'] == "" || $order['date'] < $timeleft) {
   $callback_url = $settings['site_url'] . "modules/gateways/bcstatus.php?order=" . $order['id'] . "&secret=" . $order['code'] . "&membership=" . $order['membership'];
   $response = json_decode(file_get_contents($blockchain_root . "api/receive?method=create&callback=" . urlencode($callback_url) . "&address=" . $bc_address));

Answer (score 0):

You are using custom theme, where is missing blockchain.tpl file. Go to default theme and copy blockchain.tpl to your current theme. Will start working.