# Github API JSON Call returning nothing in PHP

Tags: php, json, github, github-api

I'm trying to get the data from this Api call with the Github Api. However whenever I try and get the data from it I get the below error. I cannot seem to figure out why this isn't working.

I'm running it on a localhost through PhpStorm.

Code:

```
$url = urlencode("https://api.github.com/users/devinmatte/repos");
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$obj = json_decode($json);
echo $obj;
```

Error:

```
[Sat Mar 25 20:02:14 2017] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(https%3A%2F%2Fapi.github.com%2Fusers%2Fdevinmatte%2Frepos): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/devin-matte/Documents/Git-Challenge/index.php on line 13
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is "git challenge" ?

Comment: Git-Challenge is the name of my project I'm working on. I'm trying to Game-ify contributing to git repositories for students.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are few errors:

- no need to `urlencode` the url
- you need to create context
- you need to `print_r`, `var_export` etc instead of `echo` to print content of an array.

This should do the job:

```
$url = "http://api.github.com/users/devinmatte/repos";
$opts = [
    'http' => [
        'method' => 'GET',
        'header' => [
                'User-Agent: PHP'
        ]
    ]
];

$json = file_get_contents($url, false, stream_context_create($opts));
$obj = json_decode($json);
var_dump($obj);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are url encoding the whole URI, `file_get_contents` expect 
a valid http URI :

```
$json = file_get_contents("https://api.github.com/users/devinmatte/repos");
$obj = json_decode($json);
var_dump($obj);
```

Comment: Running that code makes `$obj = NULL` despite https://api.github.com/users/devinmatte/repos definitely not being a null JSON object

Comment: I get this is my Log:
`[Sat Mar 25 20:30:15 2017] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(https://api.github.com/users/devinmatte/repos): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden
 in /home/devin-matte/Documents/Git-Challenge/index.php on line 12`

Comment: check [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545790/file-get-contents-returns-403-forbidden), it could be `allow_url_fopen` not set to `On` in `php.ini` or `user_agent` not set in `php.ini`