# Wordpress Medium API issue - 403 Forbidden on Azure

Tags: php, wordpress, azure

> Note Issue appear in Azure Server.It wont allow get details to CURL.

I have an issue with a display post in footer.When I try to get it via `file_get_content` as well as used a `CURL` but still have issue.

```
$url="https://medium.com/@username/latest?format=json";
$homepage = file_get_contents($url);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($homepage);
echo "</pre>";
```

Its work in a Linux but when I move to windows Azure after this it will give following error.

> Warning:
>   file_get_contents(https://medium.com/@username/latest?format=json)
>   [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request
>   failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden

Comment: Possible duplicate of [file\_get\_contents returns 403 forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545790/file-get-contents-returns-403-forbidden)

Comment: No its not.I have an issue in Azure Server

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is missing User-agent in your request. Better use cURL with User-agent option:

```
function curl_get_contents($url){
   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
   $data = curl_exec($ch);
   curl_close($ch);
   return $data;
}
```

Now you can get content of endpoint like this:

```
$url="https://medium.com/@hackernoon/latest?format=json";
$homepage = curl_get_contents($url);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($homepage);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: Yes its say same thing.Let me explain you my wordpress in Azure right now.

Comment: May you try get some other sites content like https://httpbin.org/ip. If it's successful, maybe Medium is blocking your IP from request.

Comment: It working for another website that hosted on linux server.

Comment: Is there any setting for allow domain in Medium?

Comment: Hmmm. I don't familar to Azure so I can't advice you. But it's only two problem: 1. Medium is blocking your IP I guess, 2. Your server certificate have problem. So add this line `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);` before `curl_exec` and try again. Hope this help.

Comment: Let me try with above option

Comment: Still getting a same issue