# File get contents work on localhost but doesn't work on server

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a problem with function which get open graph meta from url:

```
 function post_updated_set_og_description( $post_id ) {

    $url = get_field('link', $post_id);
    $page_content = file_get_contents($url);

    $dom_obj = new DOMDocument();
    @$dom_obj->loadHTML($page_content);
    $meta_val = null;

    foreach($dom_obj->getElementsByTagName('meta') as $meta) {

      if($meta->getAttribute('property')=='og:description'){ 

      $meta_val = $meta->getAttribute('content');
    }

    update_post_meta($post_id, 'og_desc', $meta_val);

}}
add_action( 'save_post', 'post_updated_set_og_description' );
```

It's working on localhost, but when i move my website on server it doesn't work. I have erroe sth like this:

> Warning: file_get_contents($url): failed to open stream: HTTP request
>   failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden in ...

I don't know how to fix it

Comment: have you checked  allow_url_fopen is ON

Comment: Possible duplicate of [file\_get\_contents returns 403 forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545790/file-get-contents-returns-403-forbidden)