# unable to fetch Instgram followers count

Tags: php

I want to fetch the count of Instagram followers but unable to fetch, i am implementing below code to fetch the number.

```
<?php
$username = 'shubhamtester14';
$response = @file_get_contents( "https://www.instagram.com/$username/?__a=1" );
if ( $response !== false ) {
    $data = json_decode( $response, true );
    if ( $data !== null ) {
        $full_name = $data['graphql']['user']['full_name'];
        $follower  = $data['graphql']['user']['edge_followed_by']['count'];
        echo "{$full_name} have {$follower} followers.";
    }
} else {
    echo 'Username not found.';
}
?>
```

Comment: you have to add some additional details to your question

Comment: What do you mean by "unable"? Do you get an error, or the wrong results, or...? Please *edit that information into your question*.

Comment: Are you sure file get contents is all json? use regex to get the json and then decode

Comment: Yes i am geeting error "Username not found."

Comment: If I remove the error control operator (`@`), I get a warning: `file_get_contents(https://www.instagram.com/shubhamtester14/?__a=1): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden`. Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545790/file-get-contents-returns-403-forbidden)